# Security Token/Cross Domain Cookie in Classic ASP?

Tags: cookies, asp-classic, token

I have an interesting conundrum.

We have a site that is a completely separate domain, we'll say http://www.x.com and our own site that is http://www.y.com. The y.com site is actually a classic ASP site, and we aren't converting it to .NET at this time.

The problem is that there is a link on x.com that redirects to y.com from a members area. We want to "authenticate" the user to make sure they are a member from the other site. If they are, they are directed to a members area on y.com. If not, they have to provide login information on y.com.

Cookies obviously don't work due to the cross domain security, but is there a way around this? I've also looked at a service for tokens, but I'm not sure exactly how that works in Classic ASP. Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did when I needed to pass information cross domain what so hash the information into one variable and pass the url/page as another variable as a post into a page on the y.com.  That page would unhash the data, set the cookies and session variables, and then do a redirect or server.transfer to the page that was passed.  The same can work going from y.com to x.com.

Comment: So, this would involve a hyperlink submitting via onclick, then the action directing to our y.com page, and then grabbing the POST data?

Comment: Yes.  I wanted to have all the posts go through one function so that I control how the hash was resolved and so I could add and remove data from it easier.  That is why I included the url/page as an extra variable in the post.  After the validation, then I would proceed to the requested page.  If would also pass the url to the login page so that the user would bypass the default login page to the requested page after the login occured